# Trouble with font awesome and react mao

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to get function working returning a list with various elements. But it I am having trouble with the icons. Any ideas? If I change the it to faHome in the function i get the icon, but I just can't get it to work in the list.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './sideNav.module.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faHome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';



const SideNavItems = () => {
    const items = [
        {
           type: styles.option,
           icon: "faHome",
           text: 'Homes',
           link: '/'
        },
        {
           type: styles.option,
           icon: 'faHome',
           text: 'News',
           link: '/news'
        }
    ];
    const showItems = () => {
        return items.map ( (item,i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i} className={item.type}>
                    <Link to={item.link}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={item.icon}
                    style={{color:'#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer', marginRight:'10'}}/>
                    {item.text}
                    </Link>
                </div>
            )
        } )         
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {showItems()}
        </div>
    )
}   
export default SideNavItems;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a string "faHome" instead of the import faHome... remove the quotes and try again.

```
{
    type: styles.option,
    icon: faHome, // this is a reference
    text: 'Homes',
    link: '/'
},
```

Here is a link to a working codesandbox sample, slightly simplified.
https://codesandbox.io/s/7r4ed

Comment: Hi Dillon - I removed the ""  and it worked! Top Man!

Comment: @DanBilly are you seeing the Icon render in the developer console?  That should fix it.  You've also got a style color set to white (#ffffff), so if your background is white your wont see it.

Comment: @DanBilly make sure to accept an answer if it solved your problem!